# Why does add_post_meta create a nested array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't figure out why that when trying to add a custom post meta value from a set of checkboxes, by default a nested array set is being created, where I would just have a single array of the values I've saved.

So when I perform `add_post_meta($post_id, 'Procedure', $_POST['bv_procedures']);` and then do a `var_dump` of the value, I am returned with this:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '13419' (length=5)
      1 => string '13416' (length=5)
```

Why is the first index there, and how can I just have a single array containing the two values?

**-- UPDATE --**

I have since noticed somewhat strange behaviour with this now:

`var_dump(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Procedure', true));` will result in this being displayed on the screen when editing this post:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string '13419' (length=5)
```

However, I'm looking in the 'Custom Fields' section, and `Procedure` is not listed in there at all, whilst other post meta pairs are. So I have no idea what's going on here, why is this not being listed? And also, I don't understand why stating `get_post_meta` to return a string value, returns an array (albeit not nested). Surely, this is a bug?

Comment: Are you using `get_post_meta`?  `and then do a var_dump of the value` of what value `$_POST['bv_procedures']`

Comment: No, im actually using `delete_post_meta`, then the above function to add the new (with all of the new post values), but that's irrelevant. I want to know why I have a nested array?

Comment: How do you know you have a nested array, when you use [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) without the 3rd argument (single) set to `true` you would get something like that.  Hence the reason I mention it.  `(mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of meta data field if $single is true.`  However if you output `$_POST['bv_procedures']` and not the results of what you stored in the DB... then it's some other issue, see.

Comment: Hmm okay, I see. doing a `get_post_meta` with a single value, returns the single array with both values

Comment: Personally I feel it's kind of stupid the way that works, I am sure they have some "legacy" reason for it over at Wordpress, but I almost never use it without the 3rd argument set to true, just one of those things...

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question, there's more that isn't right.